# python: rows of strings with single backslash paths into csv

Tags: python

How I can convert rows of strings with double backslashes:

```
myColumn =
['hot\\gas\\substance\\1',
'hot\\gas\\substance\\2',
'hot\\gas\\substance\\3']
```

Into rows of strings with single backslashes:

```
myColumn=
['hot\gas\substance\1',
'hot\gas\substance\2',
'hot\gas\substance\3']
```

And save myColumn as csv:

```
myColumn.to_csv(exportPath +'/myColumnNEW.csv', index=False)
```

Thanks

**Note** 
If I save myColumn in .csv and open it with Excel I see double backslashes in the column:
[here is the screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct13M.png)

Comment: Assuming `myColumn = [...` is a quote from your code, you don't have strings with double backslashes. You have string _literals_ with double backslashes, which are understood by Python as strings with single backslashes. [Relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: The double backslashes you see in a string literal actually denotes to one literal backslash, so there is no need for conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, I understand this, but why my csv has double backslashes in the column? See image under the note...

Comment: then just double them up, ergo 4 back slashes

Comment: Please fix your question. The code in it needs to do what you say it does, and as comments point out, it does not. @JonasWolff Or use raw strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Given**

```
import csv
import pathlib


my_column = [
    "hot\\\\gas\\\\substance\\\\1",
    "hot\\\\gas\\\\substance\\\\2",
    "hot\\\\gas\\\\substance\\\\3"
]

filepath = "test.csv"
```

**Code**

```
with open(filepath, "w", newline="\n") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    header = ["Count", "Subfolder"]
    writer.writerow(header)
    for i, s in enumerate(my_column):
        writer.writerow((i, s.replace("\\\\", "\\")))
```

Alternatively, using the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)  module:

```
with open(filepath, "w", newline="\n") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    header = ["Count", "Subfolder"]
    writer.writerow(header)
    for i, s in enumerate(my_column):
        path = pathlib.PureWindowsPath(s)
        writer.writerow((i, path))
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `myColumn = [s.replace('\\\\', '\\') for s in myColumn]`. This should replace double backslashes (4 backshlash literals) with single backsladhes (2 backslash literals).